# Jira Query Language ("bug")

Tags: jira, jql

My problem with jql is that I want to retrieve the number of issues and the issues resolved in one day, but when I do a query like:
proejct="blablabla" created **>=** -2d and created **<**-1d. I get the issues from -2d **AND** -1d. **The >= OR > doesn't make ANY difference**.

I saw that if you use the date like: proejct="blablabla" created **>=2010-11-22** and created **< 2010-11-23**. It returns issues on 22-11-2010 that is correct, BUT if I do:

created **>2010-11-22** and created **< 2010-11-23** OR

created **>2010-11-22** and created **<= 2010-11-23**

I get the SAME RESULT and the same problem is with **createdDate** (that is not possible to use with JqlClauseBuilder).

My question now is: Is it possible  to get issues from ONE day with created and using -days? without mess out the query result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer from atlassian forum By Jobin Kuruvilla:

```
This is because you are not specifying the time. Basically it will take the time as 12.00 AM.

created >2010-11-22 and created < 2010-11-23 means created after 22nd 12.00AM and before 23rd 12:00 AM which basically means created on 22nd! Same can be told of other cases as well.

Include time like: created > "2010/11/26 01:35"
```